# Low-level reading of a POST multipart request?

Tags: python, django

I have an example which I'm trying to create which, preferably using Django (or some other comparable framework), will immediately compress uploaded contents chunk-by-chunk into a strange compression format (be it LZMA, 7zip, etc.) which is then written out to another upload request to S3.

Essentially, this is what will happen:

1. A user initiates a multipart upload to my endpoint at `^/upload/?$`.
2. As chunks are received on the server, (could be 1024 bytes or some other number) they are then passed through a compression algorithm in chunks.
3. The compressed output is written out over the wire to a S3 bucket.

Step 3 is optional; I could store the file locally and have a message queue do the uploads in a deferred way.

Is step 2 possible using a framework like Django? Is there a low-level way of accessing the incoming data in a file-like object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django Request object provides a [file-like interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.read) so you can stream data from it. But, since Django always reads the whole Request into memory (or a temporary File if the file upload is too large) you can only use this API after the whole request is received. If your temporary storage directory is big enough and you do not mind buffering the data on your server you do not need to do anything special. Just upload the data to S3 inside the view. Be careful with timeouts though. If the upload to S3 takes too long the browser will receive a timeout. Therefore I would recommend moving the temporary files to a more permanent directory and initiating the upload via a worker queue like [`Celery`](http://celeryproject.org/).

---

If you want to stream directly from the client into Amazon S3 via your server I recommend using [`gevent`](http://www.gevent.org/). Using gevent you could write a simple `greenlet` that reads from a [`queue`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.queue.html) and writes to S3. This queue is filled by the original greenlet which reads from the request.

You could use a special upload URL like `http://upload.example.com/` where you deploy that special server. The Django functions can be used from outside the Django framework if you set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable and take care of some things that the middlewares normally do for you (db connect/disconnect, transaction begin/commit/rollback, session handling, etc.).

It is even possible to run your custom WSGI app and Django together in the same WSGI container. Just wrap the Django WSGI app and intercept requests to `/upload/`. In this case I would recommend using [`gunicorn`](http://gunicorn.org/) with the [`gevent worker-class`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#worker-class) as server.

---

I am not too familiar with the Amazon S3 API, but as far as I know you can also generate a temporary token for file uploads directly from your users. That way you would not need to tunnel the data through your server at all.

**Edit:** You can indeed allow anonymous uploads to your buckets. See this question which talks about this topic: [S3 - Anonymous Upload - Key prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916179/s3-anonymous-upload-key-prefix)

Comment: I do still need to tunnel through my server because of the compression I'll be applying to the output.